# Destroying Tkinter Window based on specific function return value

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to have a tkinter window be destroyed based on a return value of another function?

Here's how I have my test code working so far: I essentially thread the other function and store its value inside a queue for later use so that I can have the window open and the function running at the same time. I'm hoping to reach a specific condition within the function to have it close the window automatically. For instance, I would like to destroy the window I have when the function returns 4 just to see if we can get the window to close based on a specific return value from the threaded function. The problem is it seems like the `mainloop` line is getting in the way of the `my_data` line being accessed at all. I thought having the thread would solve the problem, but it looks like all that can happen is that function executes and we can't really do anything with the return value.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
import queue
# Create object
import threading
import queue

my_queue = queue.Queue()

def storeInQueue(f):
  def wrapper(*args):
    my_queue.put(f(*args))
  return wrapper


@storeInQueue
def get_name(number):
    list=[]
    for i in range(number):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        if i==number-1:
          return i




t = threading.Thread(target=get_name, args = (5, ))
t.start()
win=Tk()
win.geometry("500x500")
win.title("Test Window")
label=Label(win, text="We're doing a test rn", font=("Arial", 20))
label.pack()
win.mainloop()
my_data = my_queue.get()
if my_data==4:
  win.destroy()
print(my_data)
```

Just a note: I know this works pretty much exactly like the `after` command where we have the window close after a certain period of time. That's not what I'm going for, though; I'm just using this to test out having this function run while having the window open. The end goal is to be able to close the window based on a specific return value from the function.

Comment: `.mainloop()` doesn't return until the window is closed, so you're not even looking at the value in the queue until it's too late for `win.destroy()` to actually do anything.  You'd need to check the queue periodically (using `.after()` to schedule the next check) for this to have any chance of working.

Comment: To be more clear. Everything after the mainloop needs to be in a function and use get_nowait instead of get on your queue, so you do not interrupt the mainloop. This function should be repeatedly checked with an after call.